# Is this NextJS scss module working as expected or am I wrong?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass

I have one pagination.tsx component and one pagination.module.scss file containing

```
.pagination {
  ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  li {
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

    &.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    &:hover:not(.active) {
      background-color: #ddd;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

The simplified React component is

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './pagination.module.scss';

const Pagination: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.pagination}>
            <ul>
                <li className={'active'}>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Pagination;
```

PS: In real code active is set dynamically via `classNames` but here is static class

My issue is that the styles of .pagination li.active are not applied and background is not shown in `#4CAF50`

The style on the `ul` is applied fine also on just `li`

But li.active is not

Comment: I see in the generated css that the active class is changed and scoped from .active into `li.pagination_active__n_bn9`  Then I wonder how can I properly style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your li tag className value by styles.active and this should be fixed

Comment: I did that and it worked. I could not see this documented in css/scss modules under nextjs page though, I read most of it. I understood after debugging the generated styles that .active was scoped to something else like `li.pagination_active__n_bn9` but thought that the module coould resolve it itself as was under li. Was not the case